# Como passar props da react-table para outra tela

Tags: react

Criei duas telas, uma possui uma tabela usando o componente react-table que possui tres colunas: codigo, grupo e um botão editar para cada linha. A outra tela possui uma box com duas caixas de texto onde, ao clicar no botão editar eu vou para a tela de edição e quero que nas caixas de texto renderize o código e o nome do grupo respectivos daquela linha onde eu cliquei. Eu ja consigo imprimir no console o codigo e grupo especificos de cada linha separadamente ao clicar no botão mas não sei como eu levo eles para outra tela e os apresento dentro da caixa de texto na renderização, como posso fazer isso?

E puxo o nome do codigo e grupo assim:

```
Cell: (props)=> (
             <Link to='EditarGrupo'><button className='modaleditar btn btn-info'
                    onClick={() => {
                      const nome_cdgrupo = props.original.Cdgrupo;
                      const nome_grupo = props.original.Grupos;

                         console.log("Código:", nome_cdgrupo);
                         console.log("Grupo:", nome_grupo);

                      }}>

                      Editar

                      </button>
                      </Link>
```

Quero mandar o nome_grupo e nome_cdgrupo para esses inputs em outra tela:

```
<input type='text'  className='Cdgrupo_edit' defaultValue={this.props.Cdgrupo} onChange={this.handleChangeCdgrupo}></input>
 <input type='text' className='Grupos' defaultValue={this.state.Grupo} onChange={this.handleChangeGrupos}></input>
```

As informações da tabela vem de uma api, em JSON.

Essas são as imagens de como está criada a tabela e a box, para onde eu quero levar o codigo e grupo para essas caixas de texto, cada uma tela diferente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Problema oculto não explicou o que realmente faz e como tem essas informações. Complicado entender o seu problema poderia explicar da onde vem essas informações

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Perdão se não fui claro, ainda sou bem iniciante. Tentei melhorar a minha pergunta e coloquei imagens mostrando o que estou fazendo.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve criar um componente para seu botão Editar e dessa forma passar os valores como props. O componente `<Editar/>` será responsável por renderizar os inputs, enquanto na célula da tabela você substituirá tudo pela tag do componente e passará os valores do Grupo e CdGrupo como props, assim:

```
Cell: (props)=> (<Editar Grupo={props.original.Grupo} CdGrupo={props.original.Cdgrupo}/>)
```

Simulei os botões Editar renderizando os inputs que recebem as props nesse link: https://react-gzazty.stackblitz.io, mas basicamente o código dele é uma abstração do que você colocou direto na célula da tabela:

```
import React from 'react';

const Editar = (props) => {
  const {
    Cdgrupo,
    Grupo
  } = props;

  return (
    <>
    <input type='text' defaultValue={Cdgrupo}></input>
    <input type='text' defaultValue={Grupos}></input>
    </>
  );
};

export default Editar;
```

Percebi pela classe que você está utilizando uma modal. Você pode também implementar um comportamento de modal utilizando o pacote https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal. Utilizando esse pacote, você terá que deixar de usar o Link e passará a renderizar o conteúdo diretamente em cima da tabela. Dê uma olhada e avalie se vale a pena para você.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta C.Pertile! Entendi a sua resposta mas fiquei com uma duvida, no caso se eu transformar o botão Editar em componente ele perde a função de botão? No caso quando clicado me manda para outra tela.

Comment: Quando a modal, foi um erro meu. Eu ia usar mas acabei desistindo e não troquei o nome da classe do botão rsrs. Mas obrigado pela dica mesmo assim!

Comment: Você pode transferir toda a função do botão para seu componente. Ele pode ser <BotaoEditar/>, ou qualquer coisa que você quiser. Componentes são funções javascript que renderizam html.
Aqui no site do [React](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) tem uma explicação bem legal sobre isso que acho que pode clarear mais pra ti.